# Can we retrieve ad price given to the account from one click - Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, adsense

I want to make a system where when the user clicks on the ad (generated by Google Adsense), I would get on the database side, that how much money I got from this click, would be added to previous ones and I should be able to read the total earning for a particular page. It may be related to Python, PHP, or any language. Please help me, its a very big problem for me. It might require javascript .. I guess

Comment: right now, your question is simply too generic. try a few steps yourself, and put specific errors or code.

Comment: up to my knowledge  ad revenue is not fixed it fluctuates.

Comment: Yup kelvin, it fluctuates but dailymotion is working with google adsense and there's a complete information stored for each video .. how it is working .. any idea ??